# How to use Azure Firewall for ingress website traffic?

Tags: windows, azure, iis, firewall

On Azure, I have a webserver (windows VM), that runs a website in IIS using a public IP that is used in my domain's DNS records, I now want to use IDPS (intrusion detection) for network traffic towards this website via Azure Firewall.

I understand that somehow I have to re-route my network traffic flow so that it flows through the Azure Firewall.
My question is, do I update my DNS records on my domain name to point to the public IP address of the Azure Firewall, and route it from there to my VM?

Or...do I not use the public IP of the firewall at all, and place the firewall 'in the middle' of all traffic using route tables?

What Azure Firewall setup is recommended in the context of http traffic from DNS/domainnames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created webserver that runs a website in IIS using a public IP like below:

[image]

[image]

> My question is, *do I update my DNS records on my domain name to point to the public IP address of the Azure Firewall, and route it from there to my VM?*
>
> *Or...do I not use the public IP of the firewall at all, and place the firewall 'in the middle' of all traffic using route tables?*

***Yes, you can update your DNS records to point to the public IP address associated with your web server and route it from there to your VM***

you can configure the firewall to route traffic to your webserver using a NAT rule. This approach allows you to keep your existing DNS records and IP address.

[image]

With this configuration, inbound traffic will come directly to your web server. Azure Firewall will inspect and filter the outbound traffic, providing intrusion detection capabilities.

Ensure that the Azure Firewall rules are configured to permit appropriate outbound traffic and to enable the intrusion detection features based on your requirements.

Additionally, configuring default route in the route table directs all outbound traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to the private IP address of the Azure Firewall.

[image]

To know more in detail, check the below references:

[Azure Firewall Premium features | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/premium-features#idps)

[Azure-docs/firewall/features ·MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs· GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/firewall/features.md)